# Strange behavior : mixed language

Tags: gnome, language-support

With Ubuntu 20.04 TLS + Vanilla Gnome.

My native language is French, so I set ubuntu to speak french.

Since few days, I have a strange behavior:

- in the main menu, the date is in French (good)
- In top-right menu, some items are in French, some are in English
- In modalbox (for wifi password, for example), items are in English.

Any idea ?
See the enclosed capture.
[image: Mixed language]

[image: Language settings]

And also the ouput of `locale`

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr_FR:en_AU:en
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: what was strange is that appear soudainly. Before, all was good translated.

Comment: I updated the question, as asked.

Comment: There was an update of the 20.04 language packs recently, but that shouldn't reasonably result in previously translated strings turning untranslated. I would suggest that you [file a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-translations/+filebug) and state some very specific examples of strings which got untranslated. That will allow some French translator to look deeper into it.

Comment: I tried with other user in the same computer, and there is not bug for this user. Maybe a user roblem setting ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is this extension which create this problem https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1276/night-light-slider/

And so https://codeberg.org/kiyui/gnome-shell-night-light-slider-extension/issues/83